# Magento php add to cart with Custom price

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, magento, module

I have the following issue:
I make calculations via jQuery in the frontend and want to add a product to the cart with the price calculated in the frontend.

I already wrote a custom module with an AjaxController to achieve the adding to cart part, but I know struggle with setting the custom price.

My script looks like this:

```
$_prod = json_decode(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getPost('zapfsaeule_product'));

    $id = 347; // there is only this one bundle product added to the cart  viar this scipt, so a static id is enough.

    $params = array(
        'product' => $id,
        'related_product' => null,
        'bundle_option' => array(
            6 => 17, // static options for testing purpouses
            5 => 13), // 
        'qty' => 1 // static qty for testing as well
    );

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

    $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product();
    $product->load($id);

    $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
    $cart->save();

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);

    $this->getResponse()->setBody('true'); // setting response to true, because its an ajax request.
    $this->getResponse()->setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain');
```

That's the code for adding the product.
For setting the price I tried the approach as mentioned in this thread on stackexchange:
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/4318/dynamically-calculated-prices-save-before-add-to-cart

But it didn't work. I guess the event observed here doesn't occur in my case, because I wrote a custom script.

But then there still would be the problem, IF the observer approach would work, how would I pass the calculated price to the observer?

I hope you understand the problem and can help me solve it.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Martin

Comment: Don't calculate on front-end, because all users will calculate it by them self, as they want)

Comment: I know, but we need to take the risk.

The problem is as follows:
we have different bottles with different filling quantities and the customer is supposed to select the bottle and the the liquid he wants in that bottle. So we need to calculate the price for the liquid according to the filling quantity of the selected bottle.

Comment: Instead sent the quantity and the liquid kind to server and calculate price there.

Comment: okay, but how do I set the price of the product anyway?
$_product->setPrice oder setFinalPrice won't work

Comment: You need to add it in the params. The addProduct function creates an Item object out of the product and the params. If you try to change the price of the product model you change the price of the product in the shop, not on the cart. Look up the addProduct function.

Comment: thank you! already tried that. didn't really work as well. what is the parameter for the price? I can't find a good explanation for all the attributes the parameter part of the addProduct function accepts.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through `Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart::addProduct()`, there doesn't appear to be a way to set the item's price from the parameters. Instead, you'll need to add the product, then grab the resulting item, and set its price:

```
$cart->addProduct($product, $params)
    ->save();

// grab the corresponding item
$item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);

// set its custom price
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice($customPrice)
    ->save();
```

Haven't had the time to try this out, but it should be the right idea. Make sure that you set the `original_custom_price` field (using `setOriginalCustomPrice()`), not one of the other prices. The other prices are recalculated during the totals process.

Comment: Well, what part is not working? Do you see the `custom_original_price` field in the database (see table `sales_flat_quote_item`)?

Comment: Sorry, I miswrote the column name. It's actually `original_custom_price`, as per my answer.

Comment: ok. this field exists and has the price I set in it.
But the cart still displays the calculated products price.
I should remind you, that it is a bundle product I am using.

Thanks again!

Comment: Hm, that's weird. `original_custom_price` should override a cart item's price regardless of what type of product it represents (see `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract::calcRowTotal()` and `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item_Abstract::getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal()`). I'll post back if I think of anything, but in the meantime, try digging into the pricing logic to see if you can uncover anything. Place some `Mage::log()` statements into the aforementioned methods, as well as `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal::_initItem()`, and potentially a few others.

Comment: thanks! I will do that and let you know the results.
You really helped me a lot here! :)

Comment: so the log for getBaseCalculationPriceOriginal() says this: `2015-05-15T13:43:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): 34.4
2015-05-15T13:43:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): 4.5
2015-05-15T13:43:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): 29.9
2015-05-15T13:43:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): 4.5
2015-05-15T13:43:08+00:00 DEBUG (7): 29.9
2015-05-15T13:43:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): 242
2015-05-15T13:43:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): 4.5
2015-05-15T13:43:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): 29.9
2015-05-15T13:43:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): 4.5
2015-05-15T13:43:12+00:00 DEBUG (7): 29.9`
the debug for calcRowTotal seems not to work as it just throws information in the browser and ends due to not enough memory

Answer (score 1):

This comes pretty late, but I just stumbled upon this.

I got it to work like this:

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$cart->addProduct($product, 1); // 1 = qty. Pass your qty and params.

$item = $cart->getQuote()->getItemByProduct($product);
$item->setCustomPrice(0); // or some other value
$item->setOriginalCustomPrice(0); // or some other value
$item->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true); // this is crucial 

$cart->save();
Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the params don't work, fetch the returned item from `$cart->addProduct` and change the price on the item before saving the cart.

```
$item = $cart->addProduct(...);
$item->setCustomPrice(...); {or whatever price attribute you like to set}
$cart->save();
```